# Get height of element in ng-repeat after receive data from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I call an ajax request to get a list of product, then render its by using *angular's* ***ng-repeat***.

I want to get height of `div` element that contain one product in the list, but the console alway log **"0"** to the screen, I have tried to use `$timeout` after the request had done.

```
this.$timeout(function () {
    let image_id = '#image_id';
    let height = $(image_id).height();
    console.log(height);
 },0);
```

Ex: I have three items in list, and use ng-repeat to render it on browser. I want to make height of two videos equal to height of the first image.
[image]

If the list is defined in controller, it work well. But if I call an ajax request and put data to the list, the function above alway log 0 to the screen.

Comment: You can use $promise for that. That will call your function after getting the data.

Comment: Yes, I am using $promise in that request, but when call a function to get height of product image it alway return 0.

Comment: one more thing when do you set the id 'image_id', is it not same for all images in ng-repeat ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom directive to take the height from the first element and change the height of all to the same height:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="thing" ng-repeat="thing in things" same-height>
    thing {{thing}}
  </div>
</div>

    function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.things = [
    'A', 'B', 'C'
  ];
  $scope.height ="auto";
}

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('sameHeight', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$first) {

        scope.$parent.height = element[0].offsetHeight;


      }
      var height = scope.height;
      element.css('height',height+'px');
    };
  });
```

demo:http://plnkr.co/edit/n9ksMIUxTwApZQy5ooju?p=preview

Comment: I have three items in list, and use ng-repeat to render it on browser. The first image have height auto, I want to get height of first image and apply this height for two videos beside it. Please see the image : [link] (http://nimb.ws/CW2QSf)

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1. A directive could be a way to go since you then will know angular is done rendering the element. Checking the height just after assigning the scope variable may become wrong since it could very well be executed before the ng-repeat is rendered.

Comment: @becquerel It could be possible for wrong element's offsetHeight. and at last item this answer does not show how to calculate for the highest height in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If your need to pre build the div before product get loaded on view (to avoid rendering of div form 0 to auto)
you can use

```
 ng-style="height:divHeight"
```

and in cotroller you can use a service give div a height before ajax completetion by using some given standard ration base on mobile resolution.

In service

```
 getImageHeight() {
        var x = window.innerWidth * 62.8 / 100;
        var roundHeight = Math.ceil(x);
        return Promise.resolve(roundHeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, May be it helps you. This code will execute in `onload` of image so it will never show you the height `0` if image is there.

```
this.$timeout(function () {
  let image_id = '#image_id';
  var tmpImg = new Image() ;
  tmpImg.src = $(image_id ).attr('src') ;
  tmpImg.onload = function() {
   let height = $(image_id).height();
   console.log(height);
  };

},0);
```

Comment: Thanks @Manoj Lodhi, I have found another way to resolve this, Just put it into a table, not good but I need to fix it fastest.